# AES decryption 16 bytes of junk in the beginning of decrypted text

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am having a AES encrypted text which was encrypted using Java in a binary file. This is the input i use to decrypt using CryptoPP AES in c++
I am able to decrypt the text with the code. But i get some junk characters in the beginning of the decrypted text. 
I tried removing the first 16 bytes of data in the binary file assuming this would have been the IV. but that is data and not IV in the binary text.

Here is the code i use.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
    string recovered;   

    // Generate Cipher, Key, and CBC
    byte key[ AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    string sss = "9F28872C88AC24D0D1333DAAC6600A77";

    StringSource ss1((const byte*)sss.c_str(), sss.length(), true,
                 new HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::ArraySink(key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH)));

    memset( iv, 0x00, AES::BLOCKSIZE );

        string encoded;

        CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;


        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key),iv);

        CryptoPP::FileSource file_source("DecodedBase64-1.bin", true,new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(d,new CryptoPP::StringSink(recovered)));

        cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;

    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It certainly sounds like an IV. Why are you sure it isn't? (Deleting it from the encrypted file will break the decryption.)

Comment: We need to see the Java code that performs the encryption, including the way parameters like keys and IV are encoded/decoded.